# Variance vs autocovariance

Tags: probability, variance, covariance

I don't seem to understand the fundamental difference between variance and autocovariance.

Wikipedia article on **Covariance**:

> The variance is a special case of the covariance in which the two variables are identical.

Wikipedia article on **Autocovariance**:

> The autocovariance is a function that gives the covariance of the process with itself at pairs of time points.

Can you help me understand the difference? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Covariance is defined for a pair of random variables defined on the same probability space. Autocovariance is defined for a pair of values in a discrete-time stochastic process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autocovariance is used to identify the type of periodicity that a time series has. It measures how well the changes in a variable correspond to changes that happened to itself in the past.

Covariance is used to see how well two variables correspond to each other - is there some sort of relationship between them?